# converting image to cameraimageplane in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, face-detection

I am working on capturing image using google ml kit camera plugin. Below is the code that I have used to capture the picture using takePicture method. I am unable to convert image to CameraImage

````
        final picture =  await _controller!.takePicture();
       if (picture != null) {
        // Convert the picture file to bytes
        final List<int> bytes = await picture.readAsBytes();

        // Process the image using the 'google_ml_kit' package
        final CameraImage cameraImage = CameraImage.fromBytes(
          planes: [
            CameraImagePlane(
              bytes: bytes,
              width: _controller!.value.previewSize!.width.toInt(),
              height: _controller!.value.previewSize.height.toInt(),
            )
          ],
          format: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
        );
        InputImage? inputImages = _inputImageFromCameraImage(cameraImage);
       Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomePage(
                      inputImage: inputImages,
                    )),
          );
              
       }
      child: Icon(
        Platform.isIOS
            ? Icons.camera_alt_outlined
            : Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
        size: 40,
      );
        }```
````